# Average by groups in a sequence of 3D images

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, 3d

following situation. I have a time-series of 3-Dimensional images in a 4D matrix. The resolution of the 3D images is 177 * 209 * 156.
Then I have a 3D-Mask image, which carries the information to which one of 500 groups a voxel in the 3D-Image belongs, so it has the same dimension as one 3D image, but the values are [2;501] (502 actually, but the last group is "outsiders" and those will be ignored).
Now for those 3D images, I want a 500 * X matrix, which holds the average value for each group for each Image, where X is the image-count (which is 1500 in this case). The code I wrote to generate this vector (for each image) is the following:

```
...

final_vec = zeros(500, TRs);
mask_hist = get_histogram(mask_mat);
mask_hist(1) = [];
mask_hist(end) = [];

for i = 1:TRs
    TR = new_nifti_mat(:,:,:,i);

    for k = 1:numel(TR)
        if mask_mat(k) < 502 && mask_mat(k) > 1
            final_vec(mask_mat(k) - 1, i) = final_vec(mask_mat(k) - 1, i) + TR(k);
        end
    end

    final_vec(:, i) = final_vec(:, i)./mask_hist
end

...
```

The Problem with this code is, that it runs for ever. For one set of data it ran more than 12h. I know that matlab is bad with for-loops, and probably has a very elegant 1 or 2 line of codes way to do this in a fraction of the time it needs for my code

Best Regards
Uzaku

Comment: I've changed the title to better reflect the question contents. Please check if you agree

Comment: Hey, yeah, thats fine ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create example data first:

```
x = rand(4,4,2,8); %// random data
mask(:,:,1) = [ 3 2 2 3
                2 4 4 2
                2 4 4 2
                3 2 2 3 ];
mask(:,:,2) = mask(:,:,1); %// example 4x4x2 mask
```

### Approach 1: one loop and `accumarray`

Loop over each 3D images, and for each one use [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to do the average by groups:

```
mask = mask - min(mask(:)) + 1; %// so that lowest value is 1
result = NaN(max(mask(:)),size(x,4)); %// preallocate result
for n = 1:size(x,4);
    result(:,n) = accumarray(mask(:), reshape(x(:,:,:,n),[],1), [], @mean, NaN);
end
```

### Approach 2: `bsxfun` and matrix multiplication; no loops

Linearize the first three dimensions and build a zero-one mask so that accumulation of all values within each group becomes matrix multiplication:

```
mask2 = bsxfun(@eq, mask(:), min(mask(:)):max(mask(:))).'; %'
result = mask2*reshape(x,[],size(x,4)); %// sum for each group
result = bsxfun(@rdivide, result, sum(mask2,2)); %// transform sum into average
```

Comment: Check my second method. It gets rid of all loops, and should be fast because it's based on matrix multiplication

Comment: Hey, I must say, I dont really understand your second approach, it also does not work for me, the error was something about invalid types (the 4D matrix is all int16), but i dont have the exact error anymore, and can't reproduce it now, sinve my pc is busy now, and will be for the next ~20h. But your first solution reduced the runtime for this code segment from 12+h to 20mins, which is good enough :) Thx again

Comment: If the 3D matrix `x` is ìnt16` you need to cast to `double` in the second line of the second approach: `result = mask2*reshape(double(x),[],size(x,4));`